# What attributes should I use for @property?

Tags: objective-c

Is there anyway to identify when or what conditions should I use the different attributes?  I looked over the apple documentaries and it seemed quite confusing to me.  Can someone give me the definitions and some examples for them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Memory management attributes

`retain`: values are sent a `retain` message when the value is set. This is the attribute you'll use most often.

`copy`: the value is sent a `copy` message and the returned value is stored.

For properties that uses either `retain` or `copy` you must `release` the the object in `dealloc` otherwise the object will leak.

`assign`: `assign` simply copies the value. In the case of objects that means copying the objects address (no retain message is sent to the object). You should use this for when using `retain` would create a retain loop. Examples of retain loops are parent/child relationships where both objects require a reference to the other (the parent should `retain` the child, the child should `assign` the parent). An object should `assign` its delegates for the same reason. You must use `assign` for primitives values (`char`, `int`, `long` etc) too. `retain` and `copy` would not work with primitives because primitives are not objects.

Answer (score 0):

- If your property will be accessed from multiple threads, add "atomic", if you're certain not, add "nonatomic" (faster)
- If your property should never be mutated with a different value (i.e. set), add "readonly"
- If you want to allow setters, and the value is an Objective-C object, add either "retain" or "copy" (unless you're sure you want "assign" behaviour).  Copy should be used for NSString in particular, retain for most other things.  You'll probably know if you want a copy rather than retaining the same object.
- If you don't want to allow your getters to return pointers to the same object (since it may be mutated without you knowing it), add "copy"

About all I can think of off the top of my head really.  You hardly ever have to think beyond "do I want a copy or a reference?", "will this be used across multiple threads at the same time?" and "is this settable?".